# pointer to function pointer - expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, pointers

I want to acquire address of a needed function in function Check_Commands, put it in pointer fptr, and then call it. But, when trying to compile this code, I get following message:

"Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

am I missing something?

```
void main(void)
{
   ...

   void(*fptr)(CmdDataType);

   Check_Commands(&fptr);

   (*fptr)(&CmdData);
}


void Check_Commands(void (**ptrfuncptr)(CmdDataType))
{
   ...

   **ptrfuncptr=&DispFirmware;

   ...
}


void DispFirmware(CmdDataType *CmdData_ptr)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
**ptrfuncptr=&DispFirmware;
```

should just be

```
*ptrfuncptr = DispFirmware;
```

Also there's no need to dereference a function pointer when calling, the name of a function can be thought of as a pointer to it so an ordinary call works just like that through a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple issues with your code. Here's the fixed version:

```
void main(void)
{
   CmdDataType CmdData;

   void (*fptr)(CmdDataType *);

   Check_Commands(&fptr);

   (*fptr)(&CmdData);
}


void Check_Commands(void (**ptrfuncptr)(CmdDataType *))
{

   *ptrfuncptr=&DispFirmware;

}


void DispFirmware(CmdDataType *CmdData_ptr) { }
```

`fptr` is a pointer to a function which takes a `CmdDataType` pointer as a parameter, so that needed to be fixed.

And in the function `Check_Commands` the function pointer needs to be dereferenced only once.